# Problems with CMake in CentOS 6

Tags: centos, make

I try to install a software in CentOS 6.2, without success. In README file it says:

```
Requirements:
  - qt4 gui lib version >= qt4.6.x

    Note that many linux distributions split packages into a user
    and developer package and that you need to install both.

  - ALSA Version 1.0 or newer (audio/midi input/output)
  - CMake >= 2.4.6
  - libsndfile >= 1.0.19

  - recommended: JACK audio server (audio output)

  - recommended: portaudio 19
    (required for windows version)
```

when I try to install it with `make release`, I get the following:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it by installing `gcc-c++` via `yum`.

Answer (score 11):

You need c++ and some other packages.
For example:

```
# yum install gcc-c++
# yum install cmake`
Installed:
cmake.i386 0:2.6.4-1.el5.rf                                                  
Complete!
# yum install -y ncurses-devel
Installed:
ncurses-devel.i386 0:5.5-24.20060715                                         
Complete!
```