# ./configure cannot find GCC but whereis is able to?

Tags: centos, gcc, dependencies

I have the minimal install from CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso running in VirtualBox.

Due to an Apache HTTPD dependency issue, I am trying to configure pcre via:

```
./configure --prefix /usr/local/pcre/8.41
```

but I end up with:

> configure: error: You need a C++ compiler for C++ support.

I find GCC/CPP/CC via

```
whereis gcc
whereis cpp
whereis cc
```

and, respectively, receive:

> cc: /usr/bin/cc
>
> cpp: /usr/bin/cpp /usr/lib/cpp /usr/share/man/man1/cpp.1.gz
>
> gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/libexec/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz

`yum install gcc` reports:

> ...
>
> Package gcc-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>
> Nothing to do

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am quite green in regards to administering Linux from scratch but I am trying really hard to learn how to install Apache/PHP via `make` since `yum`'s latest PHP is 5.4.

Comment: Did you read the log file, like it keeps telling you to?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm sorry, which command tells me that info? I do not see anything about logs when using `./configure --prefix /usr/local/pcre/8.41`

Comment: `gcc` is a C compiler - the C++ compiler `g++` would usually be packaged separately

Comment: @steeldriver Oh boy, I have a long road ahead of me, looks like I need `gcc-c++` in specific? Would `yum install gcc*` be advisable?

Comment: @steeldriver I installed `gcc-c++` with its dependencies and it worked. If you'd like to post an answer then I would be happy to accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with CMake in CentOS 6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33658/problems-with-cmake-in-centos-6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On systems using the GCC suite of compilers, the C++ compiler is `g++` (`cpp` is the C preprocessor).

A common name to find a C++ compiler under is `c++`.  This is often a symbolic link to an appropriate C++ compiler such as `g++` or `clang++` or whatever the installed system compiler is (if it is installed).

The error message from the `configure` script indicates that there is no C++ compiler installed on your system. On your Linux, the C++ compiler is installed separately from the C compiler.

To install the GCC C++ compiler on CentOS:

```
yum install gcc-c++
```